# Issue With Animating Blender Hair Particle System

Tags: particles

I have a human model, and a hair particle system that is separate. I took my model into Mixamo and applied a walking animation to it. When I bring the model back into Blender, I am having a hard time attaching the hair particle system, and then having it automatically animated along with it (having it follow and interact with the model). The hair seems to separate when I apply the rotation and location, and also when I apply the head vertexes. It wont move either, no matter what I try.

The hair mesh I received is able to enter edit mode on the hair itself [ the verts ] and not just show you the mesh that the hair is generated from [ the scalp mesh ]. There is no sign of an original mesh used to create the hair, in so -> making it impossible to attach it to the head bone properly. Which hinders the rest of the processes.

Workflow I know of : Take the scalp mesh > make the hair > groom it > apply empty weights > assign to head bone > place armature above particle system in modifier tab > Apply dynamics on hair > and boom.. it should work..

Any help would be great. Please and thank you.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If your previous question was put on hold, address the raised issues by editing it so it can be reopened rather than post a new one, otherwise see [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)